# How do I properly declare a uniform array of structs in GLSL so that I can point a UBO at it?

Tags: opengl, glsl

The following glsl code appears in my fragment shader. The struct definition causes no problems, but my attempt to use it as the type of a uniform array causes an "invalid operation" error, which is not particularly helpful.

```
struct InstanceData
{
    vec3 rotation;
    vec3 scale;
    mat4 position;
};

layout (std140) uniform InstanceData instances[100];
```

How do I structure this code correctly so that it compiles without error, and is thus ready for me to populate with data? Note that I am using core profile version 4.5.

**Edit:** It seems to be something to do with the use of `layout (std140)`. Removal of that part allows the code to compile, though don't I need that to ensure that the glsl compiler packs the struct data in a predictable way?

**Edit:** Still not working. My entire vertex shader code looks like this:

```
#version 450

layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;
layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;
out vec4 ex_Color;
flat out int ex_Instance;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

// ------ preliminary addition of uniform block to be used soon ------
struct layout (std140) InstanceData
{
    vec3 rotation;
    vec3 scale;
    mat4 position;
};

layout (std140, binding = 0) uniform InstanceData
{
    InstanceData instances[100];
};
// -------------------------------------------------------------------

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = (projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix) * in_Position;
    ex_Color = in_Color;
}
```

Note that I haven't written any code externally to populate the uniform buffer yet, nor, as you can see above, have I adjusted my code to make use of the data either. I just want it to compile and work initially as-is (i.e. declared but not used), at which point I will add additional code to start making use of it. There's no point going even that far if the program doesn't like the declaration to begin with.

**Edit:** Finally figured out the problem by using the shader info log, like so:

```
GLint infoLogLength;
glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
GLchar* strInfoLog = new GLchar[infoLogLength + 1];
glGetShaderInfoLog(id, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);
```

In a nutshell, as Anton said, I was using `layout` incorrectly, and my uniform block had the same name as my struct, creating all kinds of confusion for the compiler.

Comment: Yes, "invalid operation" is pretty useless. Did you actually check the shader info log when you tried to compile the shader? Off the top of my head, you have a struct with 3+3+16=22 components and then you try to instantiate an array of 100 of those. That means you're trying to use 2200 uniform components for this array alone, when GLSL implementations are only required to support 1024.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I checked the constant, mine allows around 35000 components, so that can't be the error...? And even so, how then do you pass in data for several thousand instances of a thing?

Comment: I suspect you did not check it correctly. Did you query it at runtime or are you using the value defined in the header? That value is just an identifier that you use to query the real value.

Comment: I checked it at run time using GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS

Comment: As for passing larger amounts of data, that is what Uniform Buffer Objects are for. At minimum, implementations support 64 KiB of data through UBOs. You are already sort of on track to use a UBO the way your shader's written right now and that's what I thought you were doing at first because of the layout qualifier that only applies to uniform blocks.

Comment: Yeah I already figured out how to use a UBO to populate a single struct instance, specifically because this is what I'm aiming to do. How do I declare something equivalent to a large array of my struct, such that I can point the UBO at it?

Comment: In 4.5, you can use Shader Storage Buffer Objects for large (up to 16 MiB) arrays of a struct. I have an answer that shows this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23433202/initializing-structures-from-arrays-in-glsl/23434406#23434406). The biggest difference between an SSBO and a UBO in this case is that with SSBOs you don't have to include the size of the array in your declaration.

Comment: Considering that the decimal value of `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS` is 35658, I still doubt that you properly checked the value. You need to call `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS, ...)` to query the limit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### To do this portably, you should use a Uniform Buffer Object.

Presently, your struct uses 3+3+16=22 floating-point components and you are trying to build an array of 100 of these. OpenGL implementations are only required to support 1024 floating-point uniform components in any stage, and your array requires 2200.

Uniform Buffer Objects will allow you to store up to 64 KiB (minimum) of data; well exceeding the limitation above. However, you need to be mindful of data alignment when using UBOs and that is what the `layout (std140)` qualifier you tried to use is for.

```
struct InstanceData
{
    vec3 rotation;
    vec3 scale;
    mat4 position;
};

// Uniform block named InstanceBlock, follows std140 alignment rules
layout (std140, binding = 0) uniform InstanceBlock {
  InstanceData instances [100];
};
```

The struct above is not correctly aligned for `std140`, you will need to be careful when using it.

#### This is how the data is actually laid out:

```
struct InstanceData
{
  vec3  rotation;  // 0,1,2
  float padding03; // 3

  vec3  scale;     // 4,5,6
  float padding07; // 7

  mat4  position;  // 8-23
} // Size: 24 * sizeof (float)
```

`vec3` types are treated the same as `vec4` in GLSL and `mat4` is effectively an array of 4 `vec4`, so that means they all need to begin on 4-float boundaries. GLSL automatically inserts padding to satisfy these alignment rules; the changes I made above are to show you the correct way to write this data structure in C. ***You have to account for 2 floats worth of implicit padding in your structure.***

---

Regarding your edit, you do not have to worry about how GLSL packs a `struct` until you start using buffer objects.

Without using a Uniform Buffer Object, you have to use functions like `glUniform3f (...)` to set uniforms. Those functions do not directly expose the data structure to you, so packing does not matter. To set the values for an instance `N` you would call `glUniform3f (...)` using the location of "instances [N].rotation" and "instances [N].scale" and `glUniformMatrix4fv (...)` on "instances [N].position".

That would require 300 API calls to initialize all 100 instances of your struct, so you can see why UBOs are more practical (even ignoring the above mentioned 1024 limitation).

Comment: Thanks. I'd actually already worked out how to use and populate a normal uniform block from a uniform buffer (i.e. by way of binding points, etc.), my sticking point has been trying to work out how to then include an array of structs in that definition. I've updated my answer to show the full shader code; it's still not working currently, though the format is exactly as you specified.

Comment: @NathanRidley: The `layout (std140)` qualifier in your `struct` declaration is   wrong. That qualifier only works for `buffer` variables and uniform blocks. Are you checking the shader info log when you try to compile the shaders? It should be telling you that this is a parse error.

Comment: Thanks! The shader info log was something I was unaware of. With that in place, I got an actual meaningful error message which allowed me to figure out the problem.

Comment: It is possible that the vec3 was declared to `align(16)` many math libraries tend to do that.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: `vec3` in this example refers to the GLSL data type. On the C/C++ end of things you are absolutely right - a good library will do that for you, it's practically a necessity for any of the SIMD instruction sets. But I wanted to make it abundantly clear that there's 2 floats worth of invisible space taken up by this struct due to the rules of `std140`.